# Timing page render in Play 2.0 Scala Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

is it possible to measure the time it takes for a page to render--or at least the time it takes to send a page to the client--in Play Framework?

Comment: I assume you mean 2.0 with the Scala tag, but you might want to explicitly state that. I added a tag for it, but feel free to remove if you're doing 1.2.x with the Scala module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firebug to measure time it takes to send a page to the client.

[Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about metrics on the server side, then you probably want this: http://metrics.codahale.com/

If you're asking about on the client side, then Google Chrome Developer Tools has some amazing features: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxW1dCjOstE